# Camunda java equivalent for passing all variables to activity

Tags: java, camunda

I have code that creates a dummy model like this

```
BpmnModelInstance modelInstance = Bpmn.createExecutableProcess("onelongmodel")
                .name("onelongmodel")
                .startEvent()               
                .camundaAsyncBefore()
                .callActivity("oneactivity").name("oneactivity").calledElement("oneactivity")
                .endEvent()
                .done();
```

I would like to pass all the variables in and out of the activity which I can do by adding to the bpmn file

```
  <extensionElements>
       <camunda:in variables="all" />
       <camunda:out variables="all" />
    </extensionElements>
```

I would like to do this step in java. How do I change the java code above to add this option?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for

```
private void deployProcess(String eventName) {

 BpmnModelInstance modelInstance = Bpmn.createExecutableProcess(PROCESS_ID)
  .startEvent()
  .userTask(USER_TASK_ID)
  .endEvent()
  .done();

 ExtensionElements extensionElements = modelInstance.newInstance(ExtensionElements.class);

 ModelElementInstance taskListener = extensionElements.addExtensionElement(CAMUNDA_NS, "taskListener");

 taskListener.setAttributeValueNs(CAMUNDA_NS, "class", ModelExecutionContextTaskListener.class.getName());

 taskListener.setAttributeValueNs(CAMUNDA_NS, "event", eventName);

 UserTask userTask = modelInstance.getModelElementById(USER_TASK_ID);

 userTask.setExtensionElements(extensionElements);

 deploymentId = repositoryService.createDeployment().addModelInstance("process.bpmn", modelInstance).deploy().getId();
}
```

[Reference here](https://www.codota.com/code/java/classes/org.camunda.bpm.model.bpmn.instance.ExtensionElements)